# How do I say "One day on a sunny sunday" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "One day on a sunny Sunday morning" in German?

> Eines Tages eines sonnigen Sonntagmorgens bin ich mit meiner Schwester im Park zum Training gelaufen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't we already know it's sunny because it's Sunday? Just kidding :)

I'd say...

> An einem sonnigen Sonntagmorgen

Comment: Good answer! Its the shortest (hence best) way to express this :)

Answer (score 6):

So there is the literal translations:

> Eines Tages an einem sonnigen Sonntagmorgen ...
>   Eines Tages, ein sonniger Sonntagmorgen, ...

But this versions are not really good style as both, *"Eines Tages"*, and *"ein sonniger Sonntagmorgen"* are an expression for the same indefinite day.

So we'd probably say something more along the line of

> Eines sonnigen Sonntagmorgens ... *(omitting the day because a sunday is a day)*

or, if we need the day for an accurate translation

> Eines Tages, es war ein sonniger Sonntagmorgen, ...